# Mapping Objects

Tags: c#, reflection, mapping

what is the best Solution for mapping class object to lightweight class object by example:

Customer to CustomerDTO both have the same properties names, i was thinking of the best optimized solution for mapping between them , i know reflection slow me down badly , and making methods for every mapping is time consuming so any idea ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Reflection probably doesn't slow you down as much as you think.

Comment: im mapping objects between layers to lose couples

Comment: In the approaches I've used I've described the DTO in some language like XSD or Protocolbuffer "language" and generated the code from that. You can then generate code for many/any? language such as C#, java et al.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). There's also [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) and [Emit Mapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: automapper is so slow i tried it and tested it is slower than doing the mapping manual with 20 times !

Comment: @Zeus. Indeed - but does that have a perceptible impact on your system?

Comment: Did you use the latest version? I know that Jimmy Bogard made some performance improvements recently.

Comment: yeah i used the latest version, and yeah i cant use something that is slower with 20 times, i was wondering if there is any other techniques people are using .

Comment: im gonna test emit mapper and give feedback

Comment: also i need to try ValueInjecter

Comment: A new mapper, faster than anything i tried before is https://github.com/maurosampietro/UltraMapper. Give it a try

Answer (score 2):

If reflection is slowing you down too much, try Fasterflect: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/fasterflect_.aspx

If you use the caching mechanism, it is not much slower than hand-written code.

Comment: im going to try that out and i will give feed back

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing about with this, and have the following observations. Should Customer inherit from CustomerDTO or read/write to a CustomerDTO? I've found that some DTO generators only generate dumb fixed size array collections for vectors of data items within the DTO others will allow you to specify a LIST<> or some such collection. The high-level collection does not need to appear in the serialised DTO but effects which approach you take. If your solution adds high-level collections then you can inherit if it doesn't then you probably want to read/write to a intermediate DTO.

I've used Protocol Buffers and XSDObjectGenerator for my DTO Generation (at different times!).

Answer (score 0):

A new alternative is [UltraMapper](https://github.com/maurosampietro/UltraMapper).

Is faster than anything i tried up to Feb-2017. (2x faster than Automapper in any scenario)

It is **more reliable** than AutoMapper (no StackOverflows, no depth limits, no self-reference limits).

UtraMapper is **just 1300 lines of code** instead of more than 4500+ of Automapper and it is easier to understand, maintain and contribute to the project.

It is actively developed but at this moment it **needs community review**.
Give it a try and leave a feedback on the page project!.